# How can I easily convert from numeric Enums to string or number and vice versa in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums, type-conversion

It's quite confusing, with all the different syntax. I wish there was a simple, neat, way to deal with any similar situation in my code without having to always wonder how to write it.

```
enum Direction {
  Up, Down, Left, Right
}
```

I would like to convert `Direction` or any other `Enum` in my code in the following way:

- Enum <-> string
- Enum <-> number
- number <-> string

Examples:

```
let test = Direction.Left;
enumToString(test); // -> 'Left'
enumToNumber(test); // -> 2
stringToNumber('Left'); // -> 2
stringToEnum('Left'); // -> Direction.Left
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I was able to make all of the requested converter functions (with [`Generics`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)) while satisfying Typescript's compiler. I also added `stringExists` and `numberExists` to check if a key exists.

Two important warnings: it only works with [**numeric**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) Enums, and I only tested it with Typescript **3.7.5**

```
// For *numeric* Enums !
export class EnumUtils {
  public static numberToString<T>(enumType: T, n: number): string {
    return enumType[n as keyof T] + '';
  }
  public static stringToEnum<T>(enumType: T, s: string): T[keyof T] {
    return enumType[s as keyof T];
  }
  public static enumToNumber<T>(enumType: T, s: T[keyof T]): number {
    return +s; // enumType parameter must not be removed (for type checking)
  }
  public static stringToNumber<T>(enumType: T, s: string): number {
    return EnumUtils.enumToNumber(enumType, EnumUtils.stringToEnum(enumType, s));
  }
  public static numberToEnum<T>(enumType: T, n: number): T[keyof T] {
    return EnumUtils.stringToEnum(enumType, EnumUtils.numberToString(enumType, n));
  }
  public static enumToString<T>(enumType: T, s: T[keyof T]): string {
    return EnumUtils.numberToString(enumType, EnumUtils.enumToNumber(enumType, s));
  }
  public static stringExists<T>(enumType: T, s: string): boolean {
    return s === EnumUtils.enumToString(enumType, EnumUtils.stringToEnum(enumType, s));
  }
  public static numberExists<T>(enumType: T, n: number): boolean {
    return n === EnumUtils.enumToNumber(enumType, EnumUtils.numberToEnum(enumType, n));
  }
}
```

Once you save that in a `'enum-utils.ts'` file, here are some tests you can do:

```
import { EnumUtils } from './enum-utils.ts';

enum Direction {
  Up, Down, Left, Right
}

const test1: Direction = EnumUtils.stringToEnum(Direction, 'Left');
const test2: string = EnumUtils.enumToString(Direction, Direction.Left);
const test3: Direction = EnumUtils.numberToEnum(Direction, 2);
const test4: number = EnumUtils.enumToNumber(Direction, Direction.Left);
const test5: number = EnumUtils.stringToNumber(Direction, 'Left');
const test6: string = EnumUtils.numberToString(Direction, 2);
const test7: boolean = EnumUtils.stringExists(Direction, 'Left');
const test8: boolean = EnumUtils.stringExists(Direction, 'randomstring');
const test9: boolean = EnumUtils.stringExists(Direction, '2');
const test10: boolean = EnumUtils.numberExists(Direction, 2);
const test11: boolean = EnumUtils.numberExists(Direction, 999);

// true true true true true true true true true true true
console.log(
  test1 === Direction.Left,
  test2 === 'Left',
  test3 === Direction.Left,
  test4 === 2,
  test5 === 2,
  test6 === 'Left',
  test7 === true,
  test8 === false,
  test9 === false,
  test10 === true,
  test11 === false
);
```